# How do i make .exe file known to Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, file-association

I created a venv in Pycharm, but it does not recognize file with .exe type. There is a question mark by each file.
[question marks by .exe files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJD0L.jpg)

When i run python --version to check whether i have python on my laptop at all, I do.
But once i run the commands to create an app in django, it just prints out python. Thats all.
[commands i executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjord.jpg)

I tried to add .exe into **file name patterns** in **Files opened in associated applications**, but it didn't change anything. Am i doing it in the wrong place? How do i make .exe files recognizable to Pycharm?
[.exe added to file name patterns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JiBO.jpg)

Comment: You dont need PyCharm to recognize exe files. The terminal output is completely separate from your IDE

Comment: Do you have some **other** `python3` executable in your PATH, or current directory where you run the command that just has `print("Python")`??

Comment: @OneCricketeer You were right! I was fixing my attention on those question marks in side panel, when it wasn't even a problem. Apparently i was running the wrong command to start an app in django. It was valid for older versions, but not for the newest one. I'm sorry to waste your time. I'm a newbie, so i make stupid mistakes. But u really helped me to shift my attention to the problem. Thank you!Thank you!Thank you!